# Xamarin iOS: cannot use Firebase Core in project (MT0009 error while loading assemblies)

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

After installing **Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core**, I get this error message when trying to build and deploy to iOS simulator:

```
Error while loading assemblies: /Users/{mac username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/{app name}/{build id}/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Firebase.Core.dll
```

It seems that the assembly

```
Firebase.Core.dll
```

is the only thing that is causing issues. This is the only error/ warning message I get back from the compiler. In my references node, all packages seem to be intact and in place.

This problem arose while trying to integrate Firebase into my app and so after creating a separate project and simply downloading the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core package through NuGet (without adding any code), I get the error above. I have looked at a plethora of similar issues but none of which have fixed my problem. I am now wondering if it is an issue with the package itself but it seems that I am the only one lucky enough to encounter this error. If anyone has any clue as to what might be happening please help! I am new to Xamarin and know little about c-sharp build processes, but evidently need to start learning more about said processes, so any information is useful!

**Note:** I am using Xamarin Forms but this seems like a platform-specific error since it is coming from the remote iMac.

Comment: Try installing older versions. I have had issues with specific versions now and then.

Comment: I've tried past versions to no avail. RIP might need to move on from Firebase Auth - at least until someone finds a fix. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but by some miracle or by accidental causes the problem went away. It could be that I uninstalled Firebase for the indefinite number of times that I did, then installed a much older version of the iOS.Auth Package (which installed the appropriate iOS.Core package). Seeing that building went through perfectly, I kept increasing the version of the package until I got the most recent and is surprisingly (and frustratingly) working as nothing happened. To anyone else who runs into this problem, may I suggest purging your packages and temporary Mac files? But I'm still not sure what I did correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue (MT0009) and resolved it by:

1. deleting the `.dll` causing the issue
2. manually deleting everything in `obj/` and `bin/` folders of both
   xamarin and xamarin.ios projects
3. deleting and reinstalling the nuget package linked to the issue (in
   my case it was mongodb but could be firebase or any other...)
4. restarting Visual Studio and Rebuild

Something this issue happens also when you have a `#if DEBUG` in any code file under your xamarin.ios project